# how to allow users to Create Classes and link their Database in Python Flask?

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to allow users to Create **Class** and link their **database** from the front-end to add few Inputs like ( *column definitions* )

for example I want the users to pick

1- column name

2- type of column

3- primary key ( *True or False* )

4- character count

5- unique ( *True or False* )

i want pyton to create something like this

```
class Users(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    location = db.Column(db.String(25))
    name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    title = db.Column(db.String(25))


    def __init__(self,email,password,active,confirmed_at,location,name,title):
        #self.id = id
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.location = location
        self.name = name
        self.title = title
```

also i want python to allow user to link there database ( 1 for every session )

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = '< user_input_goes_here >'
```

i can't find a title to what i'm looking for but i guess the code might be similar to the back end of the "adminer.cs50.net" because it can read the database of whatever input we

just googling and i'm not sure what i should be looking for

still its an idea i have no code yet

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = '< user_input_goes_here >'

class Users(db.Model, UserMixin):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
        password = db.Column(db.String(255))
        location = db.Column(db.String(25))
        name = db.Column(db.String(80))
        pos = db.Column(db.String(25))


        def __init__(self,email,password,active,confirmed_at,location,name,pos,entryNo,userCode):
            #self.id = id
            self.email = email
            self.password = password
            self.location = location
            self.name = name
            self.pos = pos
```

Comment: Are you trying to write a generic SQL database admin frontend like phpmyadmin ? Else I really don't see the point actually.

Comment: it's actually something else but i need to do it , it can be similar to any database viewer like **adminer**

Comment: Ok, just wanted to be sure you were not expecting to write some "fully configurable thru the web application" monstruosity <g>.  I'm not a SQLAlchemy user so I can't really help here but if you're after something with per-user dynamic schemas, I don't think you'll be able to properly use the ORM (`db.Model`) part, you'll mainly have to use the lower-level (sql) part of SQLAchemy. Well, you _could_ technically build the model classes dynamically, but this wouldn't make much sense (how could your code use a class without knowing it's exact interface ?).

Comment: exactly , i don't know the answer to this question , this is a new level for me , but i need to get there that is why i made a question here. i dont know what i'm looking for but you caught my requirements .

Comment: Well, part of the answer is that _your_ program's domain is not what's in the users databases, but what a relational dabatase is - tables, fields, relationships etc.